# Child routes not animating off when routing to another parent route

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I am creating a frontend app for learning purposes and I encountered a problem I don't quite understand how to solve.

Basically animation routing works properly on "same level" routes (parent -> parent), child -> (another child in the same parent route) but when I switch route to another parent, child route is not animating off (not doing it's :leave animation) and just leaving the dom instantly (https://streamable.com/co0gs - example - first showing animations between child routes and showing problem when clicking "Kalendarz" route).

I believe my problem is me not understanding animation queries properly but if you just point me in the right direction I will hopefully solve this problem on my own :)

Here are some files for your convenience:

Project repo: https://github.com/Micozus/Pawganiser-front/

Animation file: https://github.com/Micozus/Pawganiser-front/blob/master/src/app/animations/animations.ts

Routes module: https://github.com/Micozus/Pawganiser-front/blob/master/src/app/app-routing.module.ts

Parent route component: https://github.com/Micozus/Pawganiser-front/blob/master/src/app/app.component.html

Child routes component: https://github.com/Micozus/Pawganiser-front/blob/master/src/app/main-functions/my-pets/my-pets.component.html

Comment: can you share the code  that you did yet

Comment: I thought i did :) 
thats the repo: https://github.com/Micozus/Pawganiser-front/

Comment: `:leave` animation was not working for children routes. After converting children routes to direct paths of parent ones animation starts working

Comment: @OlegBondarenko so something like:

  `{path: 'my-pets', component: MyPetsComponent, data: {animation: 'PetPage'}}`
and
`{path: 'my-pets/start', component: PetStartComponent, data: {animation: 'PetStartPage'}},` next?
Is it like... not recommended because i would be able to outsource this routing to separate app modules?

Comment: @PawełMikos yes it will break module splitting and fix animation. As I said it is workaround  but not solution.

Comment: @OlegBondarenko thank you though :) Will come back to this problem when i'll start to module split it.

Answer (score 0):

@PawełMikos in generally it is workaround but not solution. I would be replace child routes to parent level like this :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {
 path: 'my-pets', component: MyPetsComponent, data: {animation: 'PetPage'},
 path: 'my-pets/start', component: PetStartComponent, data: {animation: 'PetStartPage'}
 path: 'my-pets/list', component: PetsListComponent, data: {animation: 'PetListPage'},
// more child routes
  ,
  {path: 'calendar', component: PetCalendarComponent, data: {animation: 'CalendarPage'}},
  {path: 'search-nearby', component: PetNearbyComponent, data: {animation: 'SearchPage'}},
  {path: 'settings', component: SettingsComponent, data: {animation: 'SettingsPage'}},
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, data: {animation: 'LoginPage'}}
];
```

Comment: That simple change made it but then I should get rid of child routing and treat that routes as same level parent routes right?

Comment: Yes , it is correct  but a bit awkward and tell the truth I expected more flexibility from Angular.

Comment: @PawełMikos  if it is correct answer could you appropriate mark it ?